# npm shrinkwrap resolved tarballs to the http://127.0.0.1:5080 url

Tags: node.js, npm, shrinkwrap

I have run `npm shrinkwrap` where some of the dependencies resolve to `http://127.0.0.1:5080` instead of the NPM registry. What's going on here? Because `npm install` does not work with these set.

here's an excerpt:

```
    "jsprim": {
      "version": "1.3.1",
      "from": "jsprim@>=1.2.2 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jsprim/-/jsprim-1.3.1.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "extsprintf": {
          "version": "1.0.2",
          "from": "extsprintf@1.0.2",
          "resolved": "http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/extsprintf/1.0.2.tgz"
        },
        "json-schema": {
          "version": "0.2.3",
          "from": "json-schema@0.2.3",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema/-/json-schema-0.2.3.tgz"
        },
        "verror": {
          "version": "1.3.6",
          "from": "verror@1.3.6",
          "resolved": "http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/verror/1.3.6.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
```

Why are these set to http://127.0.0.1:5080? How can I fix this?

The install works if I replace these with the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/(.+)/(.+).tgz

https://registry.npmjs.org/$1/-/$1-$2.tgz
```

Comment: What's the output of `npm config get registry`? Have you modified your `hosts` file recently?

Comment: The output is `https://registry.npmjs.org/` no I have not.